# how to add custom action post to admin.ajax wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to add a custom action to the admin ajax in wordrpess.

that is send_mail. I want that because, I need a custom email form that user will fill in with email address and message and press send button, my plugin will get the request and call it through admin ajax. Please, help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: http://siteurl.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php,
data:{
   'action':'send_mail',
   'fn':'send_mail'
},
success:function(data){
 // do whatever you need
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: http://siteurl.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=send_mail,
data:{   
   'fn':'send_mail'
},
success:function(data){

    }
});
```